# What is the minimal structure needed to define Exponentials intenally?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, universal-algebra

Let $(A, +, 0_A, \cdot, 1_A)$ be a commutative ring with a unity. And, let $(S, \cdot, 1_S)$ be a commutative monoid.

An "exponentiation" is an operation $S\times A\to S,$ where $(x, m)\mapsto x^m,$ *possibly partial in second variable* satisfying the properties:

$$x^{0_A}=1_S,\quad x^{1_A}=x, \quad x^{m+n}=x^mx^n,\quad (x^m)^n=x^{mn},\quad (xy)^m=x^my^m.$$

- Suppose we reduced some structure and choose $A=\mathbb{N}.$ Then the minimal structure we need to define non-negative integer exponents is just a commutative monoid $S.$
- In order to have negative integer exponents, in which case $A=\mathbb{Z},$ we need (multiplicative) inverses. So, we need $S$ to be at least an abelian group.

**Here I am wondering, what if we need the exponents also in side the algebraic structure $S$?** That is $A=S.$

Also, if we need "exponentiation" coincides with "integer exponents", then $S$ must be a ring of characteristic zero. But I am not sure how to define $a^b$ with $a,b\in S$ in this generality.
Any thoughts?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are *not* examples of what you appear to be asking for: they have an "operation" called "exponentiation" but it is not total and single-valued.  (Also, you seem to be leaving out the rather crucial property $x^1=x$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes! You are absolutely right. I was very very sloppy here. I will incorporate your points into this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: If $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are to serve as examples, they show that exponentiation can't just be a function on the domain, and you'll need some sorts of restrictions instead.

Comment: @aschepler: Corrected. EricWofsey also pointed out that in his comment. Somehow I forgot to change it at that time.

Comment: (this is not at all an answer to your question, but I thought I'd bring it up to give examples of "exotic" exponential type functions on fields.) I'm not sure if you have any interest in model theory, but if you do, you might be interested in Zilber's work on "pseudo-exponential fields". Zilber constructs fields of characteristic $0$ equipped with a total map $\exp$, which behave very similarly to the complex numbers under exponentiation, in which various nice analytic properties hold. (eg [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).)